# Entity framework - table per type issue

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I'm having troubles using Entity Framework with table-per-type inheritance. The result I get is one extra column in the '**PostComments**' table.

Here's my code so far:

**BaseComment class:**

```
   public abstract class BaseComment
   {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [AllowHtml]
        public string Content { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public DateTime TimeCreated { get; set; }

        public int? ParentId { get; set; }

        public int UserId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public CommentStatus CommentStatus { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("ParentId")]
        public virtual BaseComment Parent { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("UserId")]
        public virtual User User { get; set; }
    }
```

**PostComment class**

```
public class PostComment : BaseComment
{
    public int PostId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("PostId")]
    public virtual Post Post { get; set; }
}
```

**PageComment class**

```
public class PageComment : BaseComment
{
    public int PageId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("PageId")]
    public virtual Page Page { get; set; }
}
```

---

**My Seed() method**

```
protected override void Seed(DAL.Contexts.XPressDbContext context)
{
    context.PostComments.AddOrUpdate(new PostComment()
    {
        Content = "asdasd",
        PostId = 1,
        TimeCreated = DateTime.Now,
        UserId = 1,
        CommentStatus = CommentStatus.Approved
    });

    context.PageComments.AddOrUpdate(new PageComment()
    {
        Content = "About page comment",
        PageId = 17,
        TimeCreated = DateTime.Now,
        UserId = 1,
        CommentStatus = CommentStatus.Approved
    });
}
```

SQL result: See a **Page_Id** column in **PostComments** table. That column should not be present there.

[image: SQL result]

Can anyone tell me where I'm wrong? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Instead of using `[ForeignKey("PageId")]
    public virtual Page Page { get; set; }` make so it looks like

`public int? PageID {get; set;}
public virtual Page Page {get; set;}` - If it is correct, I'll write an answer.

Comment: Show your mapping configuration. How exactly did you configure TPT?

Comment: @haim7770: In my DbContext derived class I have DbSet<T> to represent my tables in SQL Server, which are:

    public DbSet<BaseComment> BaseComments { get; set; }
    public DbSet<PostComment> PostComments { get; set; }
    public DbSet<PageComment> PageComments { get; set; }

    Then in OnModelCreating() I use:

    modelBuilder.Entity<PostComment>().ToTable("PostComments");
    modelBuilder.Entity<PageComment>().ToTable("PageComments");

Comment: I don't know about your mapping but you may forgot the [Table("")] on each of the PostComment and PageComment

Comment: @RuiSilva: Removing the ForeignKey("") annotation does not fix the issue.

Comment: In your connection string can you change your DB to another test instance and let me know the results. Do you still see the extra column on a Fresh DB?

Comment: Yes, when I delete the database and recreate it using Configuration class's Seed method, it creates that extra column.

Comment: Does your Page class have a reference to PostComments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your TPT definition is correct. This extra column that you see does not seem to be an issue with your TPT configuration. It looks like the Page class has a reference to PostComments which is creating this extra column.

Comment: Hi, you're right, my Page class has an property ICollection<PostComment> which had to be ICollection<PageComment>.
After changing the collection type, the extra column is gone.
Thanks a lot for noticing this tiny issue. Now I'll in the future what to expect from similar column behaviours.